# Can textbook questions be quoted in the source code of an open source project?

Tags: copyright, open-source-software

The specific case I am referring to is here: https://github.com/dharmatech/Symbolism#examples. I am considering following suit and quote textbook questions which act as test cases in my own open source project related to symbolic algebra with the MIT license, however I am reconsidering this once my professor denied sharing textbook questions instead of using page and question number references due to copyright concerns.

Which is right? Can I quote textbook questions verbatim?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quoting from a book with "All rights reserved". Fair use?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41949/quoting-from-a-book-with-all-rights-reserved-fair-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not without permission

Questions in textbooks, exam papers etc. have the same copyright protection as any other literary work.

Comment: So is the link I provided a fair use or an infringement? Since I don't see any information on permission, is it safe to ssume that is is an infringement?

Comment: @Happypig375 I can’t see any textbook questions there but having permission doesn’t require you to tell people you have it (unless that’s part of the permission)

Comment: Here: https://www.github.com/dharmatech/Symbolism/tree/master/Tests%2FTests.cs and scroll to the lower part of the file. But yeah I understand your response on not having to tell people about having the permissions.

Comment: @Happypig375 I feel your question at this point is too specific to your circumstance. Why not consult a lawyer? It may be a fair use, like you have suggested.